# How do I store the string values of a functions parameters together into a single variable?

Tags: python, function, variables, parameters

I'm trying to store the three string values for the parameters in the **strings_length3** function together in a single variable. I then want to print the total length of those three stored stings by printing the length of the variable they are stored in.

```
#defining the function
def strings_length3(age, sex, name):
    print(len(age) + len(sex) + len(name))

#calling the function; the 3 string values to be stored in the variable tot
strings_length3("36", "male", "Xi")
    tot = 36 + male + Xi
    print(len(tot))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function should return (not print) the length you want. Then, assign the return value to your variable. Try:

```
def strings_length3(age, sex, name):
    return len(age) + len(sex) + len(name)

tot = strings_length3("36", "male", "Xi")
print(tot)
```

Alternatively, you can return the concatenation of the strings and apply the `len` only to the result of the function call:

```
def strings_length3(age, sex, name):
    return age + sex + name

tot = strings_length3("36", "male", "Xi")
print(len(tot))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning a value from the function. Instead of the print statement put a return call with the length of each parameter, and you can assign a variable to the function call